# 1 parent service and 2 children services

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-mediaplayer, abstract

### This is an architechture issue.

I want a Global service that runs and manage 2 children services.

Let's call it the **Streaming** and the children **radio** and **podcast**

radio and podcast both use mediaplayer api but with little diference (raio is live streaming aac and podcast is mp3 both from http url)

radio and podcast are in the same activity but in diferent fragments

the services provide callbackinterface to the fragments to update the ui

---

### streaming must :

- Run from the application start
- Run as long as the main activity is running
- Not be stopped until application finish()
- "Manage" the other services

---

### radio and podcast

- Run from when i click on a button to when i click on another button or at some point in time (predetermineted)
- Not be killed until the user decide, or some point in time (predeterminated)
- while radio run, podcast is paused or stopped ( and conversely)
- radio and podcast must extends service and implemnt the same callbacks methods

---

i have already come to a solution but i'm not satisfied

wait for some other ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

If the `parent` is in-control of both the `children`, then the triggers or buttons for child services should be `delegated` to the Parent. Infact, in your case it seems parent should be the `only interface` between children and the outside world. The parent can decide when to pause/stop which child depending on external triggers and the business logic.

Comment: I wanted to keep it general but it seems it ll be complicated see my edit

Comment: If the parent is not logically strong enough to directly manage the children, have a controller which basically co-ordinates between parent and children.

Comment: Well the idea of a parent was to ease the work and kind of coordinate the children

Comment: Well sure, your controller can handout tasks from children to the parent based on workload and what not. Think of the parent as the CPU and children as processes, what you need is a scheduler(controller). I hope I am making sense.

Comment: What does having a "manager" between the ui and the main service brings me ? i mean : the service is held globally so i can get it statically, in the fragment onClick() method i can easilly access  the play() stop() methods then the service redirect th action to the good service ?

Comment: (this is just guessing and thinking, i'm trying to improve my code here ;) if this is something you have already come across you are welcome to illustrate your thinking with some code